# any possiblility to use IPC bridge with ros fuerte?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have installed IPC_Bridge on my ubuntu with Ros fuerte but when i compile the ipc_bridge stack it doesn't make any file ( rosmake ipc_bridge_ros).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104176/any-possiblility-to-use-ipc-bridge-with-ros-fuerte??/) by [Justin NW](https://answers.ros.org/users/9101/justin-nw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you paste the output of the console ? Do you get any error or what ?
IPC_Bridge is a bit hard to setup. Btw, now there are other better options that IPC_Bridge, have a look here: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Planning/Matlab
I would recommend rosmatlab as it is very easy to setup and works perfect.

---

Originally posted by [uyaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5164/uyaseen/) with karma: 78 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0